# Can not play music from http server for over 3 seconds

Tags: java, android, url, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a music streaming app. For the music I use a URL, and for some reason, the music is playing for 3 seconds and then automatically stops. pls help me fix it.
I also get a message in the Run says: "MediaPlayer finalized without being released".
Thanks.
the code:

```
String url = "https://radio.streamgates.net/stream/1036kh"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Even if you have an exception you continue as if nothing has happened.

Comment: Do you know which toast it was if you see 'failed'?

Comment: The toast doesn't matter the code is not throwing any exception.

Comment: have you used `mediaPlayer.release()` as you have to release the media player after every song played.

Comment: I tried, it is a radio stream so I can't control the songs. I just need to stream all time